# Can COLLADA be used for partial animations / animation blending?

Tags: blender, skeletal-animation, rigging, collada

I am making a game engine, using the COLLADA format for my models. Part of the requirement for my models is partial animations, for example if the model was a person, an animation could only affect the upper body and have no effect on the lower body.

I would guess this is accomplished by having a scalar value associated with each animation-bone pair that represents the weighting of the animation applied to the bone, but in the COLLADA documentation I didn't notice any such field. So is it possible to do this with COLLADA?

And as an ancillary question, is blender able to create and export such animations?

Basically, what all do I need to know to have this type of feature in my engine?